# UITableView: offsetting selectedBackgroundView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a custom cell look that creates the look of a smaller cell and the illusion of space between them:

```
  // SETTING UP A UIView IN ORDER TO CREATE ILLUSION OF SEPARATION BETWEEN CELLS
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *clearRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,310,110)];
clearRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
clearRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
clearRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
clearRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
clearRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

// Set up Mask with 2 rounded corners
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:clearRoundedCornerView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
clearRoundedCornerView.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;

// Make a transparent, stroked laker which will display the stroke
CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
strokeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
strokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(194/255.0) green:(77/255.0) blue:(1/255.0) alpha:1].CGColor;
strokeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

// Transparent view that will contain the stroke layer
UIView *strokeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:clearRoundedCornerView.bounds];
strokeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // in case your container view contains controls
[strokeView.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];

[clearRoundedCornerView addSubview:strokeView];


[cell.contentView addSubview:clearRoundedCornerView];
```

In the following code I tried to modify selectedBackgroundView to match the view I created.  The problem I am running into is that the X Y coordinates won't change and the selectedBackgroundView stays pinned to the upper left corner of the cell.

```
- (void)installSelectedBackgroundView{

UIView *bgCustomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,310,110)];
bgCustomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
bgCustomView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bgCustomView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
bgCustomView.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;
self.selectedBackgroundView = bgCustomView;
[self setSelected:YES animated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self installSelectedBackgroundView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self installSelectedBackgroundView];
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working.  Changing the X Y in bgCustomView doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the origin of the path in installSelectedBackgroundView. As you've noticed, the origin of the bgCustomView is ignored; that's because as the `selectedBackgroundView`, it will have the same origin as the cell. So, instead, you need to offset the origin of the mask layer's path,

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectOffset(bgCustomView.bounds, 10, 10)  byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
```